# Нет подходящего конструктора по умолчанию

Tags: c++

Есть два класса, о дин наследует другой, тип наследования public.
    При компиляции выдает следующую ошибку: Нет подходящего конструктора по умолчанию.
Подскажите в чем проблема, два заголовочных файла ниже.

Integer.h

```
    class Integer {
private:
    int *_mass;
    int _system;
    int _size;
public:
    Integer(const int *mass, const int system, const int size);
    Integer(const Integer &);
    ~Integer() {
        delete[] _mass;
        _mass = nullptr;
    }
    Integer & operator=(const Integer &);
```

IntegerCalc.h

```
class IntegerCalc: public Integer {
private:
    Integer _a;
    Integer _b;
public:
    IntegerCalc(Integer &a, Integer &b) :
        _a(a), _b(b) {}; // ВОТ ТУТ ВЫДАЁТ ОШИБКУ
    ~IntegerCalc() {};
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38511/discussion-on-question-by-oleksandr-zakrevskiy-----).

Comment: As a rule, не стоит требовать больше чем тебе нужно, поэтому аргументы конструктора стоит передавать константными ссылками: `IntegerCalc(Integer const &a, Integer const &b)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш класс IntegerCalc наследуется от Integer - а значит, любой конструктор IntegerCalc должен вызывать конструктор Integer. Не конструктор поля, которые вы вызываете - а конструктор базового класса.

Поскольку вы его не вызываете - компилятор автоматически добавляет вызов конструктора по умолчанию. Получается как-то так:

```
public:
    IntegerCalc(Integer &a, Integer &b) :
        Integer(), _a(a), _b(b) {};
```

Но конструктора по умолчанию в базовом классе-то и нет! Отсюда и ошибка.

Как такую ошибку исправить - зависит от задачи. Я не очень хорошо понимаю что вы хотели своим кодом сделать.

*UPD*

> Подкласс калькулятор наследует класс чисел для того, чтобы иметь возможность использовать операторы и методы.

Так делать не следует. Для того, чтобы "использовать операторы и методы", надо использовать простой `friend`, а не наследование.  А еще лучше - не делать отдельного интерфейса для калькулятора. Почему калькулятор не может пользоваться открытыми методами?

Comment: Предполагаю, что наследование не нужно

Comment: `Friend` нарушает инкапсуляцию. Может быть, стоит использовать композицию (т. е. добавление закрытого поля)?

Comment: @Arhad ну и как вы замените friend композицией?..

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, `class IntegerCalc{public: ... private: Integer descriptor;};`? И какой смысл в дружественных отношениях, если все необходимые методы `Integer` открыты?

Comment: @Arhad никакой. А почему вы спрашиваете?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, вопрос вызвала эта фраза: `Для того, чтобы "использовать операторы и методы", надо использовать простой friend, а не наследование.`

Comment: @Arhad автор вопроса использовал наследование, чтобы *"иметь возможность использовать классы и методы"*. Не знаю, что он имел в виду - но если это были защищенные методы, то friend в такой ситуации тоже может помочь. А вот композиция - не может.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, если *защищённые* методы, тогда понятно.